# Too many calls to R.ap?

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a list, which contains items such as this:
`[{name:...}, {name:...}], ...`

I would like to extract only those elements, where name matches to any in a set of regular expressions.

I was able to do it like so:

```
const cards = yield ... //Network request to get my list of items
const matchers = [/^Remaining Space:/, /^Remaining Weight:/, /^Gross:/];
const propTester = (prop, pred) => R.pipe(R.prop(prop), R.test(pred));
const extractors = R.ap([propTester('name')], matchers);
const [ spaceCard, weightCard, grossCard ] = 
    R.ap(R.ap([R.find], extractors), [cards]);
```

Is there any way to simplify that?

Comment: Is the property `name` actually dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one possibility:

```
const matchers = [/^Remaining Space:/, /^Remaining Weight:/, /^Gross:/];
const testers = R.map(pred => R.pipe(R.prop('name'), R.test(pred)), matchers);
const extractors = R.map(R.find, testers)
const [ spaceCard, weightCard, grossCard ] = R.juxt(extractors)(cards);
```

It assumes that `'name'` is fixed and you don't need to be able to change it dynamically.  If you do, it would be slightly more work.  The main point is the use of [`R.juxt`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt), which "applies a list of functions to a list of values."

If we tried really hard, we could probably make `testers` points-free as well, but threading all that through the whole thing to make a single function from `matchers` and `cards` to your results, while possible, would likely read to less readable code.

You can see this in action on the **[Ramda REPL](http://goo.gl/dNOetx)**.

Comment: Thank you, Scott, an excellent answer as usual.

I was really happy when I came with a slightly different problem solution on my own. It was to extract all possible properties from a list of objects with some nesting.

`    const pertinentFields = ['listAfter.id', 'listBefore.id', 'list.id'];`
`    const extractors = R.ap([R.pipe(R.split('.'), R.pathOr(null))], pertinentFields);`
`    const ids = R.ap(extractors, [data]);`
So I tried modelling the above problem on this one...